# Conditional webform: Yes no, if yes extra data

Tags: forms, design, confirmation

How would you design this?

- Last tetanus vaccination: [YES][Then they fill in the year] - [NO]

Or more something like this:

[image: design]

---

Do you have an example how to design this?
Thank you!

Demian

Comment: I did this on an insurance underwriting application with a checkbox next to a textbox. If you check the checkbox, the textbox is enabled/focussed and you type in your supplementary data. The users liked it and found it easy to use. Also, easy to see at a glance which options were selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use radio buttons to have them make a choice, and leave them an option to claim they've never had one.

You can default to the top choice, so they can just enter the year. The fields in your mock are quite wide for just 4 digits, so you can use the width of the field as an affordance for how many digits.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV7HhW.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>